# Processing few AliertDialogs into one Dialog.onClickListener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I've searched into the Internet but didn't find something good.

So I tried to find my way to solve this problem.
I found one, but now I would like to ask, is this too dirty solution, whether used, whether it is dangerous?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setTitle("Title1")
         .setPositiveBUtton("Ok",this)
         .show();
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setTitle("Title2")
         .setPositiveButton("Ok",this)
         .show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      String dialogTitle = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getActionBar().getTitle().toString();
      if(dialogTitle.equals("Title1")) {
         switch(id) {
            //do smth
         }
      } else if(dialogTitle.equals("Title2")) {
         switch(id) {
            //do smth
         }
      } else {
         //no such dialog
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems incredibly fragile. I would recommend just using multiple listeners, one for each dialog:

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mFirstListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Handle first dialog
    }
};

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mSecondListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Handle second dialog
    }
};
```

Then just assign a listener per dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("First Dialog")
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", mFirstListener)
    .show();
```

Comment: Yes, I know about other ways so as e.g. few listeners (anonymous or not) and use them. Just wanted to find another solutions.

Comment: Those are pretty much your options. There's no identifying information that gets passed along in the event (without doing some not-guaranteed-to-be-safe casting) so you can either maintain some current state in your application (adding unnecessary complexity) or just use another listener.